# Display "no comments" if there is no value in a section

Tags: html, angular, typescript, directive

I have a component with a form where the user can upload a package and leave comments, but I can't make it display some value if there is no comment from the user.

```html
<div class="sub-title">Submitter comments</div>
<span *ngIf="getLastSubmitterComment(packageToReview) as comment">{{ comment }}</span>
<div class="sub-title">Reviewer comments</div>
```

I want to display e.g "No comments" when this form is sent for approval.

Comment: Haven't you tried something like `*ngIf="!comments.length"` ? Or similar?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your starting point in code? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `<span>{{ getLastSubmitterComment(packageToReview) || 'No Comments'}}</span>`

Answer (score 0):

you can use Angular structural directives in order to show/hide an element in your application

NgIf, NgFor, and NgSwitch

you can also use the ternary operator as well:

```html
<span> {{ comment.length ? comment : 'comment is not available' }} </span>
```